# min(a,b) and max(a,b) equivalent in Java?

Tags: java

In `C`, there is a `min()` convenience macro that helps make the code more readable.

In java, the shortest equivalent I know of is:

```
(a > b ? b : a)
```

But it's not as self-documenting as `min()` in my view.

Is there a built-in min() method in Java (and I just couldn't find it)? or my only recourse is to define a method like this myself?

Comment: Lol for the rep junkies - I'm surprised that this isn't a duplicate question, further, the first Google result for 'java min max' is the Math javadoc

Comment: I love how fast people throw up answers to easy questions.  Note that there IS a type issue with Math.min() but they solve it by overriding it for each different type.  Also note that for objects including the big-letters (Double, BigDecimal, ...) there is a comparable interface that defines a .compareTo() method that you could use to create a "Comparable = min(Comparable, Comparable)" function.

Comment: even if java didn't have a min function, just put the code above in a function and call it min() and it will become self documenting :)

Comment: Hasn't anybody heard of the "Delete" link? There is no need for 8 duplicate answers.

Comment: @BillK you sound cynical? Our hallowed rep-system motivates quick responses to easy questions!

Comment: @noelicus Not cynical at all--I love how anxious people are to help each other.  I really like the system here except for the occasional vote to close without a comment.

Comment: @uTubeFan With what kind of types do you want to use the min function? 
1. with built-in types, like int?
2. with user-defined-types, like an Employee class?
If you are in the second case, I think Java has abandoned you, so you'll have to create your own min function

Answer (score 62, accepted):

[`Math.min()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html)?  (Comes in several overloads for different types.)

Comment: I knew I was missing something. +1 to all who referred me to Math.min() but only one can be accepted. :)

Comment: +1: And for max you can use `Math.max`.  If you use `import static java.lang.Math.*;` you can use plain `min(a, b)` and `max(a, b)`

Answer (score 6):

have a look at the javadoc of [Math](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#min%28int,%20int%29)

you can use it like :

```
import static java.lang.Math.*;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(min(1, 0));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

See the class [`java.lang.Math` functions](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) of `min` and `max` for various types.

Answer (score 3):

do you mean Math.min(a, b) or Math.max(a,b)?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`Math`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) class. It has both `min()` and `max()` methods.

Answer (score 2):

[Math.min()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#min%28double,%20double%29)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `Math` class contains two static methods called `max` and `min` which behaves according to their names. Take a look at this [link](http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week4/40.html). Here you will find some useful examples.

Answer (score 1):

All of the `Math.max` and `Math.min` answers are wrong.  In fact there is no generic min nor max function in Java that uses the native `Comparable` interface.

Answer (score 1):

In 2022 (actually, from Java 8) we can use methods such as `Integer.min(a, b)` or `Double.max(a, b)`

Answer (score 0):

How about [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) There is a minx/max method